# Picking elements from a list

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

That's must be a very trivial question. Suppose we have the simple list

```
data = {{-1, 0}, {0.2, 0.4}, {4, 0}, {0.3, 0}, {0.2, -0.4}};
```

Then, is there a quick and elegant way to pick the element with non-zero and positive y value? In this example, we should get {0.2, 0.4}.

Comment: `Select[data, Positive[#[[2]]]&]`

Comment: Alternatively, `data//Pick[#, Sign[#[[All,2]]],1]&`

Comment: A minor variation: `Select[Positive@*Last][data]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select is a good option here.  Jason has shown in the comments how to use the `Positive` function.  If you want a bit more flexibility for future usage, you can use a standard greater than operator.

```
data = {{-1, 0}, {0.2, 0.4}, {4, 0}, {0.3, 0}, {0.2, -0.4}};    
positivedata=Select[data, #[[2]] > 0 &]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `Cases`:

```
Cases[{_, _?Positive}] @ data
```

> {{0.2, 0.4}}

Answer (score 2):

```
data = {{-1, 0}, {0.2, 0.4}, {4, 0}, {0.3, 0}, {0.2, -0.4}};
```

Pre-define pattern for better comparability

```
p = {_, x_} /; x <= 0;
```

Using `SequenceSplit` (new in 11.3)

```
First @ SequenceSplit[data, {p}]
```

{{0.2, 0.4}}

Using `ReplaceAt` (new in 13.1)

```
ReplaceAt[data, _ :> Nothing, Position[p] @ data]
```

{{0.2, 0.4}}

Using `ReplaceAll`

```
data /. p :> Nothing
```

{{0.2, 0.4}}

Using `Delete`

```
Delete[Position[p] @ data] @ data
```

{{0.2, 0.4}}

Answer (score 1):

```
data = {{-1, 0}, {0.2, 0.4}, {4, 0}, {0.3, 0}, {0.2, -0.4}, {-1, -1}};
```

Using `Pick`:

```
Pick[#, Element[#, PositiveReals] & /@ #] &@data

(*{{0.2, 0.4}}*)
```

Or using `DeleteCases`:

```
DeleteCases[data, s_ /; ! MatchQ[Sign@s, {1 ..}]]

(*{{0.2, 0.4}}*)
```

An alternative using `Pick`:

```
Pick[#, MatchQ[Thread[{##} > 0], {True ..}] & @@@ #] &@data

(*{{0.2, 0.4}}*)
```

Comment: I know it works for this case but if data have `{-1,-1}`, then your approach will not work.

Comment: Thanks for the observation, @OkkesDulgerci! See the update, please. :-)

Answer (score 1):

A [`Reap`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reap.html)/[`Sow`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sow.html) variant:

```
Reap[Sow @@@ data, _?(# > 0 &), {#2[[1]], #1} &][[2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data = {{-1, 0}, {0.2, 0.4}, {4, 0}, {0.3, 0}, {0.2, -0.4}};

Select[0 < ArcTan @@ # < π &][data]
```

> {{0.2, 0.4}}

---

*Visualization:*

```
pts = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {400, 2}];
sel = Select[0 < ArcTan @@ # < π &][pts];
unsel = Complement[pts, sel];
ListPlot[{sel, unsel}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}]
```

[image]