# Picking/selecting elements from a list

Tags: list-manipulation, manipulate

I'm trying to pick/select elements from a list based on another list's value. I haven't been able to implement the solution given to similar questions, such as [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/100696/pick-elements-from-list-separately?rq=1) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/201100/picking-elements-from-a-list). Here is a MWE:

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[a_, x_] := x^3 + x^2 - x - a
xsol[a_] := x /. NSolve[f[a, x] == 0, x, Reals]
g[a_] := xsol[a]^2 - 20/(5 - xsol[a]) + 30
h[a_] := 5*xsol[a]^3
Manipulate[{xsol[a], g[a], h[a]}, {a, 0.1, 100}]
```

For each $a$, `Manipulate` will show 3 lists: $xsol[a]$, $g[a]$ and $h[a]$ . The number of elements in each list depends on $a$ (in this particular example, it's 1 or 3).

The goal is to select elements from those 3 lists based on the value of the corresponding $g[a]$ element being larger than 25.9. For example, for $a=.1$, the three lists are ex ante:

```
{{-1.58954, -0.0922716, 0.681807}, {29.4915, 26.081, 
  25.8333}, {-20.0808, -0.00392802, 1.58473}}
```

Considering the selection criterion, I want to select only the first two elements of each list:

```
{{-1.58954, -0.0922716}, {29.4915, 26.081}, {-20.0808, -0.00392802}}
```

Now, for each particular value of $a$ (say, $a=.1$), I'm able to do it by testing each element $g[.1][[1]]$, $g[.1][[2]]$ and $g[.1][[3]]$ and selecting appropriately. However, in the context of `Manipulate`, the number of elements changes as I move the slider across the different values of $a$. For that reason, I'm at a loss on how to code it; as I move the slider, I want only the selected elements to be shown. That is, when $a=.1$ the lists shown must be:

```
{{-1.58954, -0.0922716}, {29.4915, 26.081}, {-20.0808, -0.00392802}}
```

and when $a=85$, the lists shown must be empty. Any ideas on how to achieve that?

Comment: I get xsol[0.1] = {-1.58954, -0.0922716, 0.681807} and xsol[85]={4.15769}; Also your code keeps manipulating and working till 100 on the slider. The selection criterion "for what" is g[a]>25.9? For a=85, "nothing is shown" or "nothing must be shown". Please clarify.

Comment: Little confused by the manipulation but as far as the list selection:  `a = {{-1.58954, -0.0922716}, {29.4915, 26.081}, {-20.0808, -0.00392802}}` `Transpose@Select[Transpose@a, #[[2]] > 25.9 &]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[a_, x_] := x^3 + x^2 - x - a
xsol[a_] := x /. NSolve[f[a, x] == 0, x, Reals]
g[a_] := xsol[a]^2 - 20/(5 - xsol[a]) + 30
h[a_] := 5*xsol[a]^3
Manipulate[
 Transpose@
  Select[Transpose@{xsol[a], g[a], h[a]}, #[[2]] > 25.9 &], {a, 0.1, 
  100}]
```

Is this what you are looking for?

There is quickly only a list with single elements?

Comment: yes and yes. It's a mwe, but it does convey what I was looking for. What you've proposed solve the problem.